# TSaveDialog Options ofAllowMultiSelect doesn't work properly on a W10 system

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl, delphi-2009, c++builder-2009

I have an old application, untouched for a long time, built with C++ Builder 2009, that still works fine.
That is to say ..
Today I noticed some of the `TSaveDialog->Options` don't work as intended on my Windows 10 system.  To make sure I'm not dreaming I tested the same application on an older Windows version (I tried XP) and there it worked perfectly fine as intended.

The `TSaveDialog` instance is setup at design time with `Options`:  `[ofHideReadOnly,ofAllowMultiSelect,ofEnableSizing]`

I noticed today (on Windows 10) that `ofAllowMultiSelect` doesn't work anymore ?
Instead `ofOverwritePrompt` is (incorrectly) used !
In other words I cannot select two ore more files anymore and when I select a file that already exists I first get a 'Confirm Save As' dialog.

When I compile again on my Windows 10 system, using C++ Builder 2009, in debug mode and inspect `Options`, the debugger seems to (still) properly see `ofHideReadOnly`, `ofAllowMultiSelect`, `ofEnableSizing`, yet the problem persists.  So it's not as if the values changed somehow ?

When I try at runtime:

```
SaveDialog->Options.Clear() ;
SaveDialog->Options << ofHideReadOnly << ofEnableSizing << ofAllowMultiSelect ;
```

the problem also persists !

When I remove `ofAllowMultiSelect` (at run time or at design time) 'Confirm Save As' is not shown anymore on an existing file (but I obviously also still can't select multiple files).

I'm flabbergasted by this to be honest ?  Not sure what to do next ?
I have no option to test a more recent c++ version but I'm also having difficulties comprehending how the compiler could be responsible here.

Any guidance appreciated.
Delphi tag added because of VCL overlap between c++ Builder and Delphi

Comment: Um... How would a save dialog work with multiple selections? You can't save to multiple files at the same time. This question doesn't seem to make any sense. I'm not sure that you understand what the Save in TSaveDialog means. This is not a compiler issue, it's a programmer mistake. Addmg `ofMultipleSelect` to a save dialog isn't logical.

Comment: @KenWhite because you don't see it doesn't mean it's not possible for an application to make use of it.  Fact is that this functionality is provided in `TSaveDialog` and has always properly worked under older Windows OS.  I only noticed the issue under W10 (though I did not bother to check W8).  You can see the x files via the `Files` property.  In my case x files need to be saved in one go.  Logic decides on the file names.  File name(s) provided and/or selected via the `TSaveDialog` influence that logic.  If (e.g.) 3 files need to be saved and 3 files are selected, those filenames are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows Vista and later, IF AND ONLY IF all of these conditions are met:

- the global `Dialogs::UseLatestCommonDialogs` variable is `true`
- and the `TSaveDialog::Template` property is `NULL`
- and the `TSaveDialog::OnIncludeItem`, `TSaveDialog::OnClose`, and `TSaveDialog::OnShow` events have no handlers assigned

Then `TSaveDialog` will internally use the Win32 [`IFileSaveDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifilesavedialog) interface, where the `ofAllowMultiSelect` option will be mapped to that dialog's `FOS_ALLOWMULTISELECT` option, which is **NOT SUPPORTED** by `IFileSaveDialog`, only by `IFileOpenDialog`, per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_fileopendialogoptions):

> `FOS_ALLOWMULTISELECT`
> Enables the user to select multiple items in the open dialog. **Note that when this flag is set, the [`IFileOpenDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileopendialog) interface must be used to retrieve those items.**

If the above 3 conditions are not satisfied, then `TSaveDialog` will internally use the Win32 [`GetSaveFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commdlg/nf-commdlg-getsavefilenamew) function instead, where the `ofAllowMultiSelect` option will be mapped to that dialog's `OFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT` option, which **IS SUPPORTED** by `GetSaveFileName()` <sup>1</sup>.

That is why you are seeing behavioral differences when running your app on Windows XP vs Windows 10.

So, if you want the old `TSaveDialog` behavior on newer Windows versions, you need to make sure at least 1 of those 3 conditions is not satisfied. For instance, by setting `UseLatestCommonDialogs=false` before calling `SaveDialog->Execute()`, or by assigning an (empty) event handler to one of the `OnIncludeItem`/`OnClose`/`OnShow` events.

Or, you could simply call `GetSaveFileName()` directly, instead of using `TSaveDialog` at all.

<sup>1: However, just note that on Vista+, `GetSaveFileName()` is just a wrapper for `IFileSaveDialog`, and is provided only for backwards compatibility. So, you still *might not* get the exact behavior you want even if you did use `GetSaveFileName()` on Windows 10.</sup>

---

On a side note: this code does not work the way you think it does:

```cpp
SaveDialog->Options.Clear();
SaveDialog->Options << ofHideReadOnly << ofEnableSizing << ofAllowMultiSelect;
```

The `Options` property is not actually updated! In both statements, the `Options` property is *read from*, returning a temporary `TOpenOptions`, which you are then modifying, but not *assigning back* to the `Options` property. IOW, the code is effectively doing the following:

```cpp
TOpenOptions temp1 = SaveDialog->Options;
temp1.Clear();

TOpenOptions temp2 = SaveDialog->Options;
temp2 << ofHideReadOnly << ofEnableSizing << ofAllowMultiSelect;
```

So, to update the `Options` property correctly, use this instead:

```cpp
SaveDialog->Options = TOpenOptions() << ofHideReadOnly << ofEnableSizing << ofAllowMultiSelect;
```

Comment: Thank you @Remy, very clear !  I will try a few things out based on this feedback !

Comment: Are you sure about your 'on a side note' comment ?  Because that's not what I am seeing.  Making changes to `Options` the way I do in my example *does* influence behavior !

Comment: Assigning an empty  event handler to `TSaveDialog` `OnClose` does indeed change the dialog to an older style dialog where multiple files *can* be selected !